# React - capture intermediate in shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to do a non-trivial computation as part of my implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate`. I also need to do the same computation as part of the `render` implementation. I'd like to be able to capture the result of the computation in `shouldComponentUpdate` and reuse it in my `render` implementation - i.e. I'd like to avoid computing the same value twice.

Is there a recommended way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe it should be part of the component's state?

Comment: Is `shouldComponentUpdate` allowed to change the state of the component? I know technically it can but I'm not sure that it should. Also, `this.state` may be overwritten by the time you get to `render`ing it.

Comment: Not an answer, but if the computation is non-trivial, why do you need it in `shouldComponentUpdate()`? The idea behind `shouldComponentUpdate` is to be an additional check whether render needs to run, for additional performance. From a functional perspective, `shouldComponentUpdate` is not necessary. Strictly speaking, one might say that `shouldComponentUpdate` should only contain trivial computations.

Comment: In order to `render` the component I need to do the pre-computation anyway. But doing just the pre-computation is cheaper than unnecessarily `render`ing the object. Another possibility I guess would be to cancel the `render` in some way - but I don't believe this is possible either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to define your own `setState()` wrapper inside your component like:

```
setMyState(newProps, newState) {
  var nonTrivialResult = doStuff(newProps, newState);
  newState.checkSum = nonTrivialResult;
  this.setState(newState);
}
```

And call this new method wherever you would call `setState()`, and also from `componentWillReceiveProps`.

The wrapper has access to all current props and state as well as any new props and state you pass in. That way, you should be able to do any calculation you want.

Also, you may need to call `doStuff()` from `getInitialState()` for the first round.

In this setup, your computation is done only once on every render. And you can check the result in `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

In the react lifecycle, `shouldComponentUpdate()` is called after `componentWillReceiveProps()`, so this should work..

Answer (score 0):

Can you handle it at *componentWillReceiveProps* and update the state there with the computed result? (sorry this should be more like a comment but I don't have enough rep)

Comment: That would work for a `props` update but not for a `state` update.